# Is there a way to expand groups with the XDSM diagram creation in OpenMDAO?

Tags: openmdao

Most of my test files involve the creation of an IndepVarComp that gets connected to a group. When I go to create an XDSM from the test file, it only shows the IndepVarComp Box and the Group Box. Is there a way to get it to expand the group and show what's inside?

This would also be useful when dealing with a top level model that contains many levels of groups where I want to expand one or two levels and leave the rest closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a `recurse` option, which controls if groups are expanded or not. Here is a small example with the Sellar problem to explore this option. The disciplines `d1` and `d2` are part of a Group called `cycle`.

```
import numpy as np
import openmdao.api as om
from openmdao.test_suite.components.sellar import SellarNoDerivatives

from omxdsm import write_xdsm

prob = om.Problem()
prob.model = model = SellarNoDerivatives()
model.add_design_var('z', lower=np.array([-10.0, 0.0]),
                     upper=np.array([10.0, 10.0]), indices=np.arange(2, dtype=int))
model.add_design_var('x', lower=0.0, upper=10.0)
model.add_objective('obj')
model.add_constraint('con1', equals=np.zeros(1))
model.add_constraint('con2', upper=0.0)

prob.setup()
prob.final_setup()

# Write output. PDF will only be created, if pdflatex is installed
write_xdsm(prob, filename='sellar_pyxdsm', out_format='pdf', show_browser=True,
           quiet=False, output_side='left', recurse=True)
```

[image: XDSM with recurse set to True]

The same code with `recurse=False` (`d1` and `d2` are not shown, instead their Group `cycle`):

[image: XDSM with recurse set to False]

To enable the recursion from the command line, use the `--recurse` flag:

```
openmdao xdsm sellar_pyxdsm.py -f pdf --recurse
```

With the function it is turned on by default, in the command line you have to include the flag. If this does not work as expected for you, please provide an example.

You can find a lot of examples with different options [in the tests of the XDSM plugin](https://github.com/onodip/OpenMDAO-XDSM/blob/master/omxdsm/tests/test_xdsm_viewer.py). Some of the options, like `recurse`, `include_indepvarcomps`, `include_solver` and `model_path` control what is included in the XDSM.

Comment: The examples if done by using the OpenMDAO-XDSM plugin and OpenMDAO 3.0. For previous versions it is possible to do this with the write_xdsm API function and with the same command line call as above:  http://openmdao.org/twodocs/versions/3.0.0/features/experimental/xdsm_visualization.html?highlight=xdsm